# Python Numpy array gives MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Trying to read images and converting them to array.

`filelist = glob.glob('filepath/*.png')
 x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)).flatten() for fname in filelist])`

This is giving me MemoryError.

Any better way to do this?

Comment: try fewer ... you don't indicate how many files and how much memory you have

Comment: 20k image files to read

Comment: works pretty well with few files.

Comment: `MemoryError` usually means Python runs out of memory (address space). There are only so many images of a certain size that you can load at the same time.

Comment: How big is one image? Assume it's a photography and it's 5MB. Then 20k files like that would occupy 100GB of memory, which is clearly too much.
Another question is if you really need to load all images at a time, or rather you can process them sequentially. If you need it for some vectorized optimization, then the best solution would be to load N images M times, where N*M=20k and N is tolerable for you RAM limit.